# Access Parent Scope in Transcluded Directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I would like to access a parent directive's scope, but I can't seem to get the right combination of settings.  Is this possible and is it the right approach?

I really want to avoid putting something like SOME_CONST (which would help me make DOM updates through control flow) in MyCtrl

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <parent>
        <child></child>
    </parent>
</div>

var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.obj = {prop:'foo'};
}

myApp.directive('parent', function() {
    return {
        scope: true,
        transclude: true,
        restrict: 'EA',
        template: '<div ng-transclude><h1>I\'m parent {{obj.prop}}<h1></div>',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            scope.SOME_CONST = 'someConst';
        }
    }
});

myApp.directive('child', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        template: '<h1>I\'m child.... I want to access my parent\'s stuff, but I can\'t.  I can access MyCtrlScope though, see <b>{{obj.prop}}</b></h1> how can I access the <b>SOME_CONST</b> value in my parent\'s link function?  is this even a good idea? {{SOME_CONST}}.  I really don\'t want to put everything inside the MyCtrl',
    }
});
```

Please see this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/binarygiant/tZ4qb/3/)

Thanks

Answer (score 42, accepted):

With `transclude: true` and `scope: true`, the `parent` directive creates two new scopes:
[image]

Scope 004 is a result of `scope: true`, and scope 005 is a result of `transclude: true`.  Since the `child` directive does not create a new scope, it uses transcluded scope 005.  As you can see from the diagram there is no path from scope 005 to scope 004 (except via private property $$prevSibling, which goes in the opposite direction of $$nextSibling -- but don't use those.)

@joakimbl's solution is probably best here, although I think it is more common to define an API on the parent directive's controller, rather than defining properties on `this`:

```
controller: function($scope) {
    $scope.SOME_CONST = 'someConst';
    this.getConst = function() {
       return $scope.SOME_CONST;
    }
}
```

Then in the `child` directive:

```
link:function(scope,element,attrs,parentCtrl){
    scope.SOME_CONST = parentCtrl.getConst();
},
```

This is how the `tabs` and `pane` directives work on Angular's home page ("Create Components" example).

Comment: @Mark Rajcok - Great answer Mark, you seem to be one of the few people on this site that actually understands Angular fully.  I have a question similar to this one but at this link: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23437113/get-property-value-from-parent-directive-within-child-directive).  My problem is that by the time the link method runs on the child directive the child directive's template has already been rendered.  This means I can't use the parent property within the child to set scope variables prior to rendering.

Comment: This is great but it seems that this value is copied rather than bound (ie. two-way data-binding)

Comment: Agree, this isn't two-way data bound. To answer the original question, the child controller simply needs to access scope.$parent and it has the benefits of inheritance and two-way data binding.

Comment: This is awesome nice and clean answer.

Answer (score 9):

Normally the way you access a parent scope variable in a directive is through bi-directional binding (`scope:{model:'=model'}` - see [the angular guide on directives](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)) in the directive configuration), but since you're using transclusion this is not so straight forward. If the child directive will always be a child of the parent directive you can however configure it to require the parent, and then get access to the parent controller in the child link function:

```js
myApp.directive('parent', function() {
  return {
    scope: true,
    transclude: true,
    restrict: 'EA',
    template: '<div ng-transclude><h1>I\'m parent {{obj.prop}}<h1></div>',
    controller: function($scope) {
        $scope.SOME_CONST = 'someConst';
        this.SOME_CONST = $scope.SOME_CONST;
    }
  }
});

myApp.directive('child', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    require:'^parent',
    scope:true,
    link:function(scope,element,attrs,parentCtrl){
        scope.SOME_CONST = parentCtrl.SOME_CONST;
    },
    template: '<h1>I\'m child.... I want to access my parent\'s stuff, but I can\'t.  I can access MyCtrlScope though, see <b>{{obj.prop}}</b></h1> how can I access the <b>SOME_CONST</b> value in my parent\'s link function?  is this even a good idea? {{SOME_CONST}}.  I really don\'t want to put everything inside the MyCtrl',
  }
});
```

See this update: http://jsfiddle.net/uN2uv/

Answer (score 6):

I just had the same problem and finally solved it with the angular manual ;)

In short: you need to use a **controller in** your **parent** directive and **require** that controller **in** your **child** directive. This way you are able to get your parent properties.

See https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive 
Chapter:  Creating Directives that Communicate

I changed your fiddle to use a controller, now you can access your constant:
https://jsfiddle.net/bbrqdmt3/1/

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.obj = {prop:'foo'};
}

myApp.directive('parent', function() {
    return {
        scope: true,
        transclude: true,
        restrict: 'EA',
        template: '<div ng-transclude><h1>I\'m parent {{obj.prop}}<h1></div>',
        controller: function($scope) {
            this.getConst= function() {
                return 'someConst';
            }                        
        },
    }
});

myApp.directive('child', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        require : '^parent',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            scope.value= ctrl.getConst();
        },
        template: '<h1>I\'m child.... I want to access my parent\'s stuff, but I can\'t.  I can access MyCtrlScope though, see <b>{{obj.prop}}</b></h1> how can I access the <b>SOME_CONST</b> value in my parent\'s link function?  is this even a good idea? {{value}}.  I really don\'t want to put everything inside the MyCtrl',
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a transclude fn in the arguments of the link fn after the controller.

```
myApp.directive('parent', function() {
  return {
    scope: true,
    transclude: true,
    restrict: 'EA',
    template: '<div><h1>I'm a parent header.</h1></div>',
    link: function (scope, el, attrs, ctrl, transclude) {

        transclude(scope, function (clone, scope) {
            element.append(clone); // <-- will transclude it's own scope
        });

    },
    controller: function($scope) {
        $scope.parent = {
            binding: 'I\'m a parent binding'
        };
    }
  }
});

myApp.directive('child', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    require:'^parent',
    scope:true,
    link:function(scope,element,attrs,parentCtrl){

    },
    template: '<div>{{parent.binding}}</div>' // <-- has access to parent's scope
  }
});
```