# Why isn't my directive's $parent scope set to the parent directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a simple scenario

```
<thead grid-columns pager-info="pagerInfo" onsort="onSort()">
    <tr>
        <th width="15%"><column sortby='FName'>Name</column></th>
        <th width="17%"><column sortby='Mobile'>Number</column></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

The idea is that since ALL my columns need an `onsort` defined, I can just define it once on the parent.

But, why doesn't my child directive (column) have it's `$parent` set to the grid-columns directive? Instead, `scope.$parent` is set to the controller scope, so I can't work out how to access my parent directive scope from my child directive.

Both of the directives have an isolated scope, and my child directive transcludes:

```
ngApp.directive('gridColumns', function () {
    // Attribute-based wrapper round the columns that allows us to capture the pagerInfo and set a sort handler.
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            pagerInfo: '=',
            onsort: '='
        }
    };
});

ngApp.directive('column', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            sortby: '@'
        },
        template: "<span><a ng-click='sort()' ... </span>",
        link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
            scope.sort = function () {

                // I want to call scope.$parent.onsort, but scope.$parent is the controller !

                // scope.$parent.onsort(scope.sortby);
            };
        }
    };

});
```

Comment: Can you check this url @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20212354/angularjs-accessing-parent-directive-properties-from-child-directives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try `require`:

```
ngApp.directive('column', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            sortby: '@'
        },
        template: "<span><a ng-click='sort()' ... </span>",
        require:"^gridColumns",
        link: function (scope, el, attrs,gridColumnsController) {//inject gridColumnsController
            scope.sort = function () {
                 gridColumnsController.onsort(scope.sortby);//call the controller's onsort function.
            };
        }
    };

});
```

Update your `gridColumns` to expose `onsort`:

```
ngApp.directive('gridColumns', function () {

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            pagerInfo: '=',
            onsort: '&' //also update the function binding
        },
        controller:function($scope){
           this.onsort = function (sortBy){
                $scope.onsort({param:sortBy});
           }
        }
    };
});
```

Your HTML:

```
<thead grid-columns pager-info="pagerInfo" onsort="onSort(param)">
```

You could have more information at this: [AngularJS - $emit only works within it's current scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21402756/angularjs-emit-only-works-within-its-current-scope)

Comment: Nice, never come across that before. For anyone else, it's documented quite well here: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: @Matt Roberts: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, but I think you need to change your function binding to make it work.

Comment: Thanks, I'd snipped some of the code out of the function to avoid posting too much code-noise, so yeah as it is it wouldn't work :)