# Access value from parent directive in child directive

Tags: angularjs

I have the following markup:

```
<div parent="john">
   <div child>Child 1 </div>
   <div child>Child 2</div>
</div>
```

And the following child directive:

```
angular.module("app").directive("child", child);

function child($parse) {
  var child = {
    link: link,
    replace: false,
    restrict: "A"
  };
  return child;
  function link(scope, element, attributes) {
  }
}
```

How can I create a Parent directive (where a value is set, for example, John) and on Child directive access the parent value?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20212354/angularjs-accessing-parent-directive-properties-from-child-directives?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Use `isolate scope` to define a two-way binding for your `child` directive. Reference: [AngularJS directive guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

An `isolate scope` is defined in the `child` as:

```
return {
   scope: {
       attName: '='
   },
   // ... others
};
```

Use the child as: `<div child att-name="parentVar"></div>`.

The value `parentVar` is an value on the `parent`'s scope. When this value is changed in the `parent`, the value will be propagated into the `child` by Angular.

======================

Upon request, here is an example: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wk7wfy7s/1/)

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you are saying. Could you, please, give me a more full example? Thank you.

Comment: I would prefer to not set the att-name at child level because the value will always be the one in parent. And I can have many childs ... So a change in parent would force me to change all code. I really want child to work only when parent exists and the value is always taken from parent

Comment: Actually i do not get what you mean from the comment. This answer is for what you asked in the question. Probably you want to explore more options of the directives. I believe there is some solution for your scenarios.

Comment: I tried to follow your example but I still get the value undefined on child. Could you, please, take a look at my example: http://jsfiddle.net/puLoaz93/. What am I missing?

Comment: Why not you compare yours and mine?

Comment: From your code, I guess you may be a freshman to Angular. I suggest you to follow some tutorials and write more code. You will get used to it very soon.

Answer (score 0):

You can require the directive, and then access to the parent controller:

```
angular.module("app").directive("child", child);

function child($parse) {
  var child = {
    require: '^parent',
    link: link,
    replace: false,
    restrict: "A"
  };
  return child;
  function link(scope, element, attributes, parentCtrl) {
    //Here you have access to the parent controller
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried that but wasn't able to make it work. Could you take a look at my online example? http://jsfiddle.net/puLoaz93/