# Get Property Value From Parent Directive within Child Directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have two Angular directives, one nested inside the other as shown below.

**HTML**

```
<gss-response-group response-group-id="43" response-group-title="'Group Title'">
  <gss-response-option option-id="5" option-text="'Very Often'" option-value="5.00" options-inline="true" type="'radio'"></gss-response-option>
  <gss-response-option option-id="6" option-text="'Often'" option-value="4.00" options-inline="true" type="'radio'"></gss-response-option>
  <gss-response-option option-id="7" option-text="'Sometimes'" option-value="3.00" options-inline="true" type="'radio'"></gss-response-option>
  <gss-response-option option-id="8" option-text="'Rarely'" option-value="2.00" options-inline="true" type="'radio'"></gss-response-option>
  <gss-response-option option-id="9" option-text="'Never'" option-value="1.00" options-inline="true" type="'radio'"></gss-response-option>
</gss-response-group>
```

**responseGroup.template.html**

```
  <div class="gss-response-group">
    <label class="gss-response-group-title" ng-if="responseGroupTitle != null">{{responseGroupTitle}}</label>
    <placeholder></placeholder>
  </div>
```

**responseOption.template.html**

```
<div ng-class="{'gss-response-option': optionsInline}">
  <input class="gss-{{type}}-option" id="{{id}}" name="{{groupName}}" type="{{type}}" value="{{optionValue}}" />
  <label class="gss-option-text" for="{{id}}">{{optionText}}</label>
  <div class="gss-specifyanswer" ng-if="specify">
    <label class="gss-specifyanswer" ng-if="specifyText != null">{{specifyText}}</label>
    <textarea class="gss-specifyanswer" maxlength="5000" disabled></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
'use strict';

angular.module( 'gssApp', [ 'gss.directives' ] );

angular.module( 'gssApp' )

.controller( 'gssAppController', [

    '$scope',
    '$http',
    '$rootScope',

    function ( $scope, $http, $rootScope )
    {

    }] );

var directiveModule = angular.module( 'gss.directives', [] );

directiveModule.directive( 'gssResponseGroup', function ()
{
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      responseGroupTitle: '=',
      responseGroupId: '='
    },
    templateUrl: 'responseGroup.template.html',
    link: function ( scope, element, attrs, ctrl, transclude )
    {
      element.find( 'placeholder' ).replaceWith( transclude() );
    },
    controller: [

        '$scope',
        '$rootScope',
        '$element',
        '$attrs',

    function ( $scope, $rootScope, $element, $attrs )
    {

    }]
  };
} );

directiveModule.directive( 'gssResponseOption', function ()
{
  return {
    restrict: 'E',    
    transclude: true,
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      responseGroupId: '=',
      optionId: '=',
      optionText: '=',
      optionValue: '=',
      type: '=',
      optionsInline: '=',
      specify: '=',
      specifyText: '='      
    },
    templateUrl: 'responseOption.template.html',
    controller: [

        '$scope',
        '$rootScope',
        '$element',
        '$attrs',

    function ( $scope, $rootScope, $element, $attrs )
    {
      // HOW DO I GET THE PARENT DIRECTIVE'S SCOPE TO USE THE
      // responseGroupId FROM IT?
      $scope.id = 'rgID' + '_' + $scope.responseGroupId + '_' + $scope.optionId;
      $scope.groupName = 'rg' + '_' + $scope.responseGroupId;
    }]
  };
} );
```

I want the child directive to have access to the "response-group-id" field in the parent.  How do I do this?  I was able to get the value by having the parent directive be required by the child directive and then getting it within the "link" method of the child directive but by then it was too late to be applied to the child template.

[Code in Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/eACnxU9V1CjziQ3m6ccX?p=preview).

Also, if anyone could tell me why the CSS isn't being applied within my Plunker project, I'd appreciate it (though not a big deal).

Comment: ... why do you need the inner directive at all? Couldn't you just store the input definitions in an Object then iterate over it using ng-repeat?

Comment: If you must know though, there should be a `$parent` object attached to your scope

Comment: I need the inner directive for other purposes.  This is just a stripped down example just to get to the heart of the issue I'm having.

Comment: Do you care to elaborate on where I should put the $parent object?  I've already tried $scope.$parent from within the child but it isn't returning the parent directive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To share data between directives, it is recommended to define the shared data on the controller of the parent directive, and access it from the link function of the child directive (see last example "Creating Directives that Communicate" in [angular Developer Guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)).

So your parent directive's controller would look like:

```
function ( $scope, $rootScope, $element, $attrs )
{
  this.id = $scope.responseGroupId;
}]
```

And your child directive would look like:

```
directiveModule.directive( 'gssResponseOption', function ()
{
  return {
  ...
  require: '^gssResponseGroup',
  link: function(scope, element, attrs, gssResponseGroupCtrl) {
    scope.id = 'rgID' + '_' + gssResponseGroupCtrl.id + '_' + scope.optionId;
    scope.groupName = 'rg' + '_' + gssResponseGroupCtrl.id;
  }
```

Note that this solution will break if the `responseGroupId` is interpolated. If the value changes, it will not be reflected in the controller `id` property since it is only set once. Instead of the `id` property, the controller would have to define a getter method that always checks the latest value of `$scope.responseGroupId`.

Comment: I tried this and I am able to get the responseGroupId into the child directive.  However, by the time the "link" method runs, it has already "rendered" the child directive using its template.  So setting responseGroupId on the child at this point doesn't help me.  It needs to be set before the child directive gets initialized.  Do you think making the parent directive's priority higher might fix this?

Comment: I don't believe that changing the priority on the directives will have any effect.

Comment: There are actually two link functions, a 'pre' and a 'post' link. The `link: function` syntax defines the 'post' link method. You can try `link: { pre: function(... }` instead. This should cause the method to be called before the directive is rendered, but I don't know if it will be early enough to solve your new problem.

Comment: I'll give this a shot and let you know.  Thanks for the help.  It would be nice if the documentation for AngularJS was a little better.  I don't even mean that they need perfect descriptions of all the functionality, but would be nice to at least know the different methods available.  I was unaware that there was a "pre" and "post" link function.

Comment: Your code above (the actual answer not the code in the comment) worked.  I must have had a typo in my code when I claimed that it didn't work.  I'm sure that your comment of the pre-link function would also work but it isn't necessary.  I also found more info about directive functionality on the compile page of Angular [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile).  You would think it should be on the directive page, but alas 'tis not.

Comment: Sometimes when the page loads, it states that it cannot find the "parent" directive "gssResponseGroup".  Do you know what would cause this and/or how to fix it?

Comment: I haven't run into that before, but I am suspicious it is a timing issue, where the child is trying to render before it has been properly transcluded into the DOM. Try changing the gssResponseGroup link function to a pre-link as described above, so that it will be called before the link method of the children is called.

Comment: In general, the order for setting up a directive is: (1) controller; (2) pre-link; (3) set up children; (4) post-link. However, if there are child directives that need to load an html template, their set-up might occur after the post-link of the parent directive.

Comment: It had to do with how I was transcluding the inner elements.  See my question here. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23478391/controller-directivename-required-by-directive-ngclass-cant-be-found)

Answer (score 0):

Though I think you're making things a lot harder than they need to be, here's a solution:

```
<gss-response-group response-group-id="43">
  <gss-response-option response-group-id="responseGroupId"></gss-response-option>
</gss-response-group>
```

Then in your `responseGroupOption` directive:

```
return {
  // Other Logic...
  scope: {
    responseGroupId: '='
  }
};
```