# Controller <directiveName>, Required by Directive 'ngClass', Can't be Found

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I get the error "Controller 'gssResponseGroup', required by directive 'ngClass', can't be found!" when using the linked Plunker files.  Problem is, sometimes it works perfectly fine and other times I get this error.  My guess is that the order of loading/compiling of the directives is not consistent.

Anyone have any ideas?

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/eACnxU9V1CjziQ3m6ccX?p=preview)

I don't see why it states that it can't be found.  It is defined right above in the same JavaScript file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't recreate your error, but I am guessing the imperative `transclude()` call in your link function is creating a race condition. You're using pre-1.2 transcludes with 1.3, so take a look at the current docs for your transcluding needs: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

I'm also pretty sure the error is not referring to a dependency injection lookup failure, but because the `require: '^gssResponseGroup',` line in your sub-directive can't find the not-yet-instantiated / linked controller of a parent directive, since it's being transcluded in an ad-hoc way.

Comment: OK, that fixed the issue.  You are probably right about the race situation as the error appeared intermittently.  The reason I was doing it with the replace within the link function was because I didn't want the extra "wrapper" div (the one with the "ng-transclude").  So out of pure stubbornness, is there a way to put the transcluded inner elements directly into the template without a container element?

Comment: You should be able to add `ng-transclude` to the parent as an attribute. Doesn't give you as much control since the transcluded content always goes below the literal content, but it'll save you an element.

Comment: Hmmm... I tried that but it didn't work.  Like I said, it's no big deal I just wanted to see if it was possible.  It "transcluded" everything with the ng-transclude attribute including any child elements.