# Custom child directive accessing scope of parent

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am having two custom directives in my angularJS app. One act as a parent and other act as child. I am trying to access parent's scope inside child directive. But I am not getting the desired output.

```
<div ng-controller="CountryCtrl">
{{myName}}
    <div ng-controller="StateCtrl">
        <state nameofthestate="'Tamilnadu'">
            <city nameofthecity="'Chennai'"></city>
        </state>
    </div>
</div>
```

and my script looks like

```
var app = angular.module("sampleApp",[]);
app.controller("CountryCtrl",function($scope){
    $scope.myName = "India";
});
app.controller("StateCtrl",function($scope){
});
app.directive("state",function(){return {
    restrict : 'E',
    transclude: true,
    scope : { myName  : '=nameofthestate'},
    template:"**   {{myName}} is inside {{$parent.myName}}<br/><ng-transclude></ng-transclude>"
}});
app.directive("city",function(){return {
    restrict : 'E',
    require:'^state',
    scope : { myName  : '=nameofthecity'},
    template:"****   {{myName}} is inside {{$parent.myName}} which is in {{$parent.$parent.myName }}<br/> "
}});
```

Corresponding JSFiddle available in https://jsbin.com/nozuri/edit?html,js,output

The output which i am getting is

```
India
** Tamilnadu is inside India
**** Chennai is inside India which is in Tamilnadu
```

and the expected output is

```
India
** Tamilnadu is inside India
**** Chennai is inside Tamilnadu which is in India
```

Can anyone educate me what i am doing wrong here?

Comment: sorry , but your fiddle is not working for me.

Comment: hi http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23437113/get-property-value-from-parent-directive-within-child-directive this may help you it's look like what you want to do

Comment: You can make a custom transclude with `transclude : 'element'`. The constructor is available in `link : function(scope, element, attrs, Ctlr, transclude){}`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The city directive $parent is a transcluded scope of state directive.

The transcluded scope of the state directive is inherit for $parent of state directive which is controller thus that is why $parent.MyName = India.

The $parent of transcluded scope is the state directive isolated scope ( scope = {} ) that is why $parent.$parent.MyName = Tamilnadu ( Part of Angular 1.3 update )

[image]

Bit of detail of what happen : 
[How to access parent scope from within a custom directive *with own scope* in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17900201/how-to-access-parent-scope-from-within-a-custom-directive-with-own-scope-in-an)

> transclude: true - the directive creates a new "transcluded" child
>   scope, which prototypically inherits from the parent scope. If the
>   directive also creates an isolate scope, the transcluded and the
>   isolate scopes are siblings. The $parent property of each scope
>   references the same parent scope.
>
> Angular v1.3 update: If the directive also creates an isolate scope,
>   the transcluded scope is now a child of the isolate scope. The
>   transcluded and isolate scopes are no longer siblings. The $parent
>   property of the transcluded scope now references the isolate scope.

Also Matthew's answer is correct for parent-child directive communications.

Answer (score 15):

Does this work for you? Adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16866749/access-parent-scope-in-transcluded-directive).

There isn't a straightforward way to access the transcluded content's parent element, so we inject the parent controller into the child to access its scope.

```
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

  app.controller("CountryCtrl",function($scope){
      $scope.myName = "India";
  });

  app.controller("StateCtrl",function($scope){
  });

  app.directive("state",function(){return {
      restrict : 'E',
      transclude: true,
      scope : { myName  : '=nameofthestate'},
      template:"**   {{myName}} is inside {{$parent.myName}}<br/><ng-transclude></ng-transclude>",
      controller: function ($scope) {
        this.getName = function () {
          return $scope.myName;
        }
      }
  }});

  app.directive("city",function(){return {
      restrict : 'E',
      require:'^state',
      scope : { myName  : '=nameofthecity'},
      template:"****   {{myName}} is inside {{parentName}} which is in {{$parent.myName }}<br/> ",
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
        scope.parentName = ctrl.getName();
      }
  }});
```

Comment: yes. It works. But i am accepting @kwan245's answer as it explains what mistake i did.. :) Thanks Metthew

Comment: I've used this approach, but in my case the variable holding the name is an array that may change. Is there a way of dealing with this situation as the view doesn't update for me in this case?

I know I could use watches but would want to avoid this as much as possible.

I have an example here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42676713/sharing-data-between-child-directives/42677394

Answer (score 2):

> When AngularJS encounters transclude , it clones the HTML before
>   replacing it with the template or templateUrl contents. Then, when it
>   encounters ng-transclude , it compiles the transcluded content, but
>   links it to the parent scope instead of the isolated scope of the
>   directive. Thus, the transcluded content still has access to the
>   parent controller and its content, while the directive HTML has an
>   isolated scope (or a new scope, as the case might be).

AngularJS Up and Running

Answer (score 1):

Check out sollution of my directive, it works with a lot of parrents. What I done was to remove transclude and require params. Do not bother about dirty html, just watch js, simple as f.. :D

```
    CRM.directive('inputwv', function ($compile) {
    var getTemplate = function(contentType) {
        var template = '';

        switch(contentType) {
                case '3':
                    template = '<input type="number" ng-init="inputHide[$parent.$index][$index]=false" ng-blur="inputHide[$parent.$index][$index]=false" ng-Enterd="updateRecord(row[0], $parent.$index)" ng-Enteru="inputHide[$parent.$index][$index]=false" ng-model="row[$index]" ng-change="row[$index]" ng-value="row[$index]" ng-Right-Click="click(element, $index, $parent.$index )" ng-esc="inputHide[$parent.$index][$index]=false" style="cursor:cell;border-bottom:0px;width:100px">'
                    break;
                case '0':
                    template = '<input type="text" ng-init="inputHide[$parent.$index][$index]=false" ng-blur="inputHide[$parent.$index][$index]=false" ng-Enterd="updateRecord(row[0], $parent.$index)" ng-Enteru="inputHide[$parent.$index][$index]=false" ng-model="row[$index]" ng-change="row[$index]" ng-value="row[$index]" ng-Right-Click="click(element, $index, $parent.$index )" ng-esc="inputHide[$parent.$index][$index]=false" style="cursor:cell;border-bottom:0px">'
                    break;
                case '1':
                    template = '<input type="text" ng-init="inputHide[$parent.$index][$index]=false" ng-blur="inputHide[$parent.$index][$index]=false" ng-Enterd="updateRecord(row[0], $parent.$index)" ng-Enteru="inputHide[$parent.$index][$index]=false" ng-model="row[$index]" ng-change="row[$index]" ng-value="row[$index]" ng-Right-Click="click(element, $index, $parent.$index )" ng-esc="inputHide[$parent.$index][$index]=false" style="cursor:cell;border-bottom:0px">'
                    break;
                case '2':
                    template = '<textarea class="materialize-textarea teal-text" type="text" ng-init="inputHide[$parent.$index][$index]=false" ng-blur="inputHide[$parent.$index][$index]=false" ng-Enterd="updateRecord(row[0], $parent.$index)" ng-Enteru="inputHide[$parent.$index][$index]=false" ng-model="row[$index]" ng-change="row[$index]" ng-value="row[$index]" ng-Right-Click="click(element, $index, $parent.$index )" ng-esc="inputHide[$parent.$index][$index]=false" style="cursor:cell;border-bottom:0px">'
                    break;
                case '4':
                    template = '<input type="text" ng-init="inputHide[$parent.$index][$index]=false" ng-blur="inputHide[$parent.$index][$index]=false" ng-Enterd="updateRecord(row[0], $parent.$index)" ng-Enteru="inputHide[$parent.$index][$index]=false" ng-model="row[$index]" ng-change="row[$index]" ng-value="row[$index]" ng-Right-Click="click(element, $index, $parent.$index )" ng-esc="inputHide[$parent.$index][$index]=false" style="cursor:cell;border-bottom:0px">'
                    break;
                case '5':
                    template = '<input type="date" class="datepicker" ng-init="inputHide[$parent.$index][$index]=false" ng-blur="inputHide[$parent.$index][$index]=false" ng-Enterd="updateRecord(row[0], $parent.$index)" ng-Enteru="inputHide[$parent.$index][$index]=false" ng-model="row[$index]" ng-change="row[$index]" ng-value="row[$index]" ng-Right-Click="click(element, $index, $parent.$index )" ng-esc="inputHide[$parent.$index][$index]=false" style="cursor:cell;border-bottom:0px"><script type="text/javascript">$(\'.datepicker\').pickadate({selectMonths: true, selectYears: 15});</script>'
                    break;
                default:
                    template = '<textarea class="materialize-textarea teal-text" type="text" ng-init="inputHide[$parent.$index][$index]=false" ng-blur="inputHide[$parent.$index][$index]=false" ng-Enterd="updateRecord(row[0], $parent.$index)" ng-Enteru="inputHide[$parent.$index][$index]=false" ng-model="row[$index]" ng-change="row[$index]" ng-value="row[$index]" ng-Right-Click="click(element, $index, $parent.$index )" ng-esc="inputHide[$parent.$index][$index]=false" style="cursor:cell;border-bottom:0px">'
            }

        return template;
}

    var linker = function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.html(getTemplate(attrs.typ)).show();

        $compile(element.contents())(scope);
    }

    return {
        restrict: "E",
        link: linker
    };
});
```