# Sharing Data between Child Directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have three directives defined:

- **Parent**

  This should share variables between the other two directives - Child One and Child Two.
- **Child One**

  This contains an input field representing a search term. Whenever this changes I use a link function to update the variable stored in the parent controller.

  In real world use I will then carry out a search based on this term and update the array. But for simplicity in this example, I just want to create a new array with length 1, which I want to be populated with the search term as it's value.
- **Child Two**

  This should show the resultant array.

For some reason this does not work, if I set the length of the Array to 0 and push the value I will see the view update in Child Two (I have commented out the code which achieves this), but I want to understand why setting the array value doesn't work.

I understand that a service would be suitable here, but this directive may be re-used multiple times on the same page so I don't want the scope to clash between each item on the page.

Why doesn't the view get updated with the code I currently use?

```js
var app = angular
  .module('SampleApplication', [])
  .directive('parent', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      transclude: true,
      template: "<div ng-transclude></div>",
      controller: function($scope) {
        this.searchTerm = "";
        this.arrayContainingSearchTerm = [{value: ''}];
      
        this.updateSearchTerm = function(searchTerm) {
          this.searchTerm = searchTerm;
          
          //When this array is assigned - it doesn't get updated in the view
          this.arrayContainingSearchTerm = [{value: searchTerm}];
          
          //This will update the view.
          //this.arrayContainingSearchTerm.length = 0;
          //this.arrayContainingSearchTerm.push([{value: searchTerm}]);
        };
        
      }
    }
  })
  .directive('childOne', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      require: '^^parent',
      template: "<div><h1>Child One</h1><input ng-model='searchTerm'></input></div>",
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, parentController) {
        scope.$watch('searchTerm', function(newValue, oldValue) {
          parentController.updateSearchTerm(newValue);
        });
      }
    }
  })
  .directive('childTwo', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      require: '^^parent',
      template: "<div><h1>Child Two</h1><h2>Value below should be: {{searchTerm}}</h2><h2>{{arrayContainingSearchTerm}}</h2></div>",
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, parentController) {
        scope.searchTerm = parentController.searchTerm;
        scope.arrayContainingSearchTerm = parentController.arrayContainingSearchTerm;
      }
    }
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="SampleApplication">
  <parent>
    <child-one></child-one>
    <child-two></child-two>
  </parent>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Children scope automatically inherit the parent's scope and can specifically access the parent's scope with $parent / requiring the parent controller but take note that siblings cannot [easily] access each others scope. So, the solution is to update the parent scope and reflect the parent scope changes back to the targeted child.

You don't need to update the child scope since the child scope is automatically inherit from parent scope. Also rather than watch the searchTerm ngModel, just use attrs.ngModel in the childOne directive.

```js
var app = angular
.module('SampleApplication', [])
.directive('parent', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    template: "<div ng-transclude></div>",
    controller: function($scope) {
      this.searchTerm = "";
      this.arrayContainingSearchTerm = [{value: ''}];

      this.updateSearchTerm = function(searchTerm) {
        this.searchTerm = searchTerm;

        //When this array is assigned - it doesn't get updated in the view
        this.arrayContainingSearchTerm = [{value: searchTerm}];

        //This will update the view.
        //this.arrayContainingSearchTerm.length = 0;
        //this.arrayContainingSearchTerm.push([{value: searchTerm}]);
      };

    }
  }
})
.directive('childOne', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    require: '^^parent',
    template: "<div><h1>Child One</h1><input ng-model='searchTerm'></input></div>",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, parentController) {
        // Just use attrs.ngModel
        parentController.updateSearchTerm(attrs.ngModel);
    }
  }
})
.directive('childTwo', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    require: '^^parent',
    template: "<div><h1>Child Two</h1><h2>Value below should be: {{searchTerm}}</h2><h2>{{arrayContainingSearchTerm}}</h2></div>",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, parentController) {
       // Comment/remove this since the scope is automatically inherit from parent scope
      //scope.arrayContainingSearchTerm = parentController.arrayContainingSearchTerm;
      //scope.searchTerm = parentController.searchTerm;
       // scope.arrayContainingSearchTerm = parentController.arrayContainingSearchTerm;

    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="SampleApplication">
  <parent>
    <child-one></child-one>
    <child-two></child-two>
  </parent>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I can't access the scope of the parent controller using the  parentController.$scope syntax.

Also, do you mean to assign variables to themselves in the link function?

Could you provide an answer snippet please?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I cannot use this answer with Transclusion because the parent scope gets lost but transclusion wasn't critical in my case. I re-wrote my directive to have child-one and child-two hardcoded and the directives communicate with each other without any issues.

Answer (score 1):

Your second directive is not aware of changes you're making afterwards - you need to `$watch` them:

```js
var app = angular
.module('SampleApplication', [])
.directive('parent', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    template: "<div ng-transclude></div>",
    controller: function($scope) {
      this.searchTerm = "";
      this.arrayContainingSearchTerm = [{value: ''}];

      this.updateSearchTerm = function(searchTerm) {
        this.searchTerm = searchTerm;

        //When this array is assigned - it doesn't get updated in the view
        this.arrayContainingSearchTerm = [{value: searchTerm}];

        //This will update the view.
        //this.arrayContainingSearchTerm.length = 0;
        //this.arrayContainingSearchTerm.push([{value: searchTerm}]);
      };

    }
  }
})
.directive('childOne', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    require: '^^parent',
    template: "<div><h1>Child One</h1><input ng-model='searchTerm'></input></div>",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, parentController) {
      scope.$watch('searchTerm', function(newValue, oldValue) {
        parentController.updateSearchTerm(newValue);
      });
    }
  }
})
.directive('childTwo', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    require: '^^parent',
    template: "<div><h1>Child Two</h1><h2>Value below should be: {{searchTerm}}</h2><h2>{{arrayContainingSearchTerm}}</h2></div>",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, parentController) {
      scope.arrayContainingSearchTerm = parentController.arrayContainingSearchTerm;
      scope.searchTerm = parentController.searchTerm;
      scope.$watch(function() {
        scope.arrayContainingSearchTerm = parentController.arrayContainingSearchTerm;
      });

    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="SampleApplication">
  <parent>
    <child-one></child-one>
    <child-two></child-two>
  </parent>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that works but I was wondering if there was a way I could achieve this without watches? I can see my code getting quite verbose if I have to watch numerous variables.